# Free yellow fever vaccination in Bogota airport?

Tags: health, colombia

I've heard that you can get free yellow fever vaccination in Bogota airport, I'm wondering if I can still do this in Feb. next year?

Answer (score 8):

**Yes you can.**

If you go on the [El Dorado Airport](http://eldorado.aero/servicios/servicios-de-salud/) official website, they have a health section where they detail those services.
You can get a free vaccine any day of the week between 7 and 7, including yellow fever. Just go to the Fontibon Hospital area on the second floor of the airport.
It seems you might need [basic Spanish](http://backdoorpath.com/free-yellow-fever-vaccination-in-bogota-colombia/) to explain what you want though.

[image: screenshot from airport website]

Whether you can still get it next February is very possible, found some old [threads](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g294074-i3499-k6314461-Yellow_fever_immunization_in_Bogota-Bogota.html) from 2013 where people were discussing that vaccine so it seems doubtful they would cancel that service now.

Comment: Great Thanks! I will update it when I come back.

Answer (score 2):

I got this jab from the airport about 5 years ago, I know they have redeveloped El Dorado but I imagine that this service is still freely available you will just need to find in what part of the airport it is being offered. When I had it you did not need an appointment simply turn up and get jabbed!